# Reading from a file, putting through an array and printing into file

Tags: c, arrays, file

I'm trying to make a program that translates words that are in a file and puts them in another file. Here I'm trying to read the words and put them into an array so I can search for them later and then print back into another file the translated word.

For the moment I'm trying to read and print from the array:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char rom_eng[4][2], fran_eng[4][2];
    int i, j;
    FILE* re = fopen("rom_eng.txt", "r");
    FILE* out = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    if (re == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
         for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
             fscanf(re, "%s", &rom_eng);

    }

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            fprintf(out, "%s \n", rom_eng);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The words in the file are like this:

```
 - word word
 - word word
```

The output is the same last word repeatedly printed in the out file.

Comment: can you explain in detail about your problem. I could not get from the problem description.

Comment: The problem is that in the out file all I get is the last word repeated like wordwordwordword

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. You need to use array subscripts to add data to different elements of the arrays.  Your arrays are also too small for your sample data; `word` won't fit in an array smaller than 5 without running into problems (questionable practices).  So, the second dimension should be at least 5 — more if words can be longer than just `word`.  Maybe 32 would be a reasonable upper limit?

Answer (score 1):

You define : `char rom_eng[4][2], fran_eng[4][2];`
And then you read: `fscanf(re, "%s", &rom_eng);`

You 're not supposed to put the `'&'` before `rom_eng` because it is defined as a char, and chars are already pointers to adresses, so in this case you dont need to put the '&' to point to the adress.

Comment: Sorta...you're right that the `&` is not wanted, but the code should be using `rom_eng[i]` and then worrying about buffer overflows because the last dimension is only big enough for single letter 'words'.  Although, having said that, the code has two levels of loop; maybe there needs to be a 3D array `char rom_eng[4][2][32];` and pass `rom_eng[i][j]` to `scanf()`.  It's all a bit unclear.